# SSRS report: unrelated list of values appears when empty date/time parameter is clicked

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS reports with date/time parameters which work fine.
Strange thing happens when I click date/time parameter's box while it's empty: dropdown list of unrelated text lines appears below the clicked box. Here's how it looks:

[image: Here is the illustration:]

It appears in all reports with date/time parameters. In each report the values that appear are different.
In the Development Studio while previewing a report it doesn't happen at all.
The parameters are defined as usual in very simple manner.
Google search didn't help. :(
Can anyone give me a hint, please, what is it and how to get rid of it? SSRS version: 14.0.1016.232, MVS version 2015.

Comment: To be clear, this only happens on the deployed version of the report, is that correct?

Comment: @AlanSchofield: that's right!

Comment: I looks to me like it could be the contents of your browsers 'type-ahead' or 'auto-complete' history. The field name probably has the same name as another field that you've input data into, in the past. Try using another browser and if that's OK trying clearing your browser history. If you are using Chrome it's part of the "Autofill" data. You could follow this guide to removing specific entries if that's better in your scenario.
https://osxdaily.com/2018/07/20/how-delete-chrome-autofill-suggetsions/

Comment: @AlanSchofield: thank you for the reply! I also thought about the autofill. But the lines that appear look like list of fields or columns... I don't believe I inputted this into some textbox in Chrome....

Comment: @AlanSchofield: You are right, it doesn't happen in IE...

Comment: @AlanSchofield: I deleted the entries as it's suggested in the link you provided. Can we count you comment as successful answer?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept , glad it helped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks to me like it could be the contents of your browsers 'type-ahead' or 'auto-complete' history.

The field name probably has the same name as another field that you've input data into, in the past.

Try using another browser and if that's OK trying clearing your browser history. If you are using Chrome it's part of the "Autofill" data.

You could follow this guide to removing specific entries if that's better in your scenario.

https://osxdaily.com/2018/07/20/how-delete-chrome-autofill-suggetsions